# How can I implement or develop my own twitter authentication provider?

Tags: dotnetnuke

I want to allow my users to log in with their Twitter accounts.

What do I need to implement this? I want to know all the processes that DNN follows for user authentication.

I'm using DotNetNuke 6.2, Visual studio 2008, SqlServer 2008

Any answer will be welcome, including links to pages to learn about it, online tutorials, etc. Excuse my English but I speak spanish!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best place to learn how to create new authentication provider is to review existing authentication providers. You can download source code from dotnetnuke.codeplex.com.

[Here is a link from Joe Brinkman's post](http://www.theaccidentalgeek.com/post/2009/07/13/DotNetNuke-Tips-and-Tricks-12-Creating-your-own-Authentication-Provider.aspx) which is 2-3 year old but still usefull since nothing has changed much in terms of implementing authentication provider.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Thank you Prashant! I've read it the Joe Brinkman's post, and I implement my own authentication provider based in the standar authentication. But now, What changes in the code I need to implement to the user can loggin with Twitter user and password?

Comment: Once you deploy and enable the provider, you will see another tab in login screen from which users will be login